# Print PDF as double-sided mini (half-page) booklet

Tags: windows, gratis, printing

On my old printer there was an option to print a regular PDF (or any series of pages) in a way such that the output would form a double-sided mini booklet, in that you would take all the printed pages and fold them in half (all at once) and you'd have a mini booklet.

I can't seem to find such an option on my new printer (an HP color laserjet).

Is there a separate software that could replicate this effect, i.e. modify the PDF in the way described above (so that the printer could just print like it normally does)?

Comment: Adobe reader has that functionality built in. What PDF viewer are you using? And does your printer support duplex printing (obviously needed for a normal booklet printing)?

Comment: You've added the [tag:gratis] tag to your question, which makes this a not-answer, but if you don't actually mind a commercial program, [BlueSquirrel's ClickBook](http://www.bluesquirrel.com/products/clickbook/) did the job for me, until all the programs I routinely use started having the functionality built-in. ClickBook also has the virtue of being able to do it with non-duplexing printers; it generates instructions for re-loading the partly-printed booklet back in the printer to finish the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDF Booklet](http://pdfbooklet.sourceforge.net/) is a great program for this, been using it for years.

[image: MainScreen01.gif]